# Python and pytest

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pytest

I installed python3.8 in my linux ubunut and pytest too, but when I am runing pytest in terminal it shows python 2.7 version. Is there any way that i can change the pytest to run with python3.

Following is the what in terminal:

```
coder_me_ilyas@ilyasnayle:~/Desktop/git/VC/scripts$ python3 add.py
Please add your name: Data Glacier
Please add your favourite sports name: Football
Please add your name: Ilyas Nayle
Please add your favourite sports name: Baseball
coder_me_ilyas@ilyasnayle:~/Desktop/git/VC/scripts$ cd ..
coder_me_ilyas@ilyasnayle:~/Desktop/git/VC$ python3 -m pytest test/test.py
============================================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/coder_me_ilyas/Desktop/git/VC
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                 

================================================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/test.py _______________________________________________________________________________________
/home/coder_me_ilyas/Desktop/git/VC/test/test.py:4: in <module>
    from scripts.add import load_json
/home/coder_me_ilyas/Desktop/git/VC/scripts/add.py:36: in <module>
    call_sport()
/home/coder_me_ilyas/Desktop/git/VC/scripts/add.py:24: in call_sport
    name = input("Please add your name: ")
/home/coder_me_ilyas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/capture.py:217: in read
    raise OSError(
E   OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please add your name: 
========================================================================================== short test summary info ==========================================================================================
ERROR test/test.py - OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================= 1 error in 0.11s ==============================================================================================
```

coder_me_ilyas@ilyasnayle:~/Desktop/git/VC/test$ pytest test.py -s
============================================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================================

```
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.18, pytest-4.6.9, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/coder_me_ilyas/Desktop/git/VC/test
collecting ... Please add your name: 
collected 0 items / 1 errors
```

and my program gives error. I tried in other computer it works but in mine it gives error.
I believe that it might be because of the python and python3 version. and I don't know how to change that. any help?

Answer (score -1):

Install python3-pytest

```
sudo apt install python3-pytest
```

See https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-pytest

then run

```
pytest-3
```

instead of

```
pytest
```